# DateTime constructor in php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have done a little experiment on php's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class. In the documentation they have suggested the syntax for creating the object of DateTime class as given.

Object oriented style:

```
public DateTime::__construct() ( [ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

Procedural style:

```
DateTime date_create ( [ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

Returns new DateTime object.

Here the first argument they have specified as mandatory, as a date/time string as specified in [Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) section. Or we have to pass `NULL` here to obtain the current time when using the $timezone parameter.

But my problem is when I am giving following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$d_ob = new DateTime('x');
echo $d_ob->format('Y-m-d');
```

It's supposed to generate exception, but it's echoing the current date time like -

```
2013-09-29
```

I am not getting the point, how it's working?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: The first argument is *not* mandatory, both arguments are optional. FYI.

Comment: X is for X-ray time zone (UTC-1100), soldier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this is not a bug, it is 'expected, but undocumented behaviour'<sup>[See the comments to the bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65747)</sup>. All single letters (except for 'j') represent military timezones, [see some code to demonstrate this](http://3v4l.org/88HEs).

There is more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones).

From [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5.2)

> The  military  standard uses  a  single  character for each zone. "Z" is Universal Time. "A" indicates one hour earlier, and "M" indicates 12  hours  earlier;  "N"  is  one  hour  later, and "Y" is 12 hours later.  The letter "J" is not used.

So to answer your question

> I am not getting the point, how it's working?

When DateTime::__construct() is passed a single value that is not a valid time string it assumes that the first parameter has been omitted and tries to parse the string as a time zone. As the RFC explains, 'x' is a valid timezone, so you will get a DateTime instance that is in timezone 'X'.

I should mention that although the constructor of \DateTime recognises these single letter zones, the constructor of \DateTimeZone [does not!](http://3v4l.org/aO6A6)

I hope that helps.

Comment: `new DateTime('zzz')` or new `DateTime('ZzZ')` will both also give today's date. It appears that this behaviour applies to repeated characters (case insensitive).