# PHP Datetime constructor returns now for strange values

Tags: php, datetime

I've discovered that the PHP \Datetime class returns "now" values for some odd inputs.  I've already seen the similar question at [DateTime constructor in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19076825/339440) -- which explains inputs such as single letters of the alphabet (they're military time zones).  But I've discovered some new oddballs that I would expect to cause an error, not return a value.  Such as...

```
new \Datetime( '.' )
new \Datetime( ',' )
```

Can anyone explain WHY these don't cause errors, and can anyone tell me what **other** odd values I should expect to return valid dates?  Is this a bug in PHP?

(Yes, I've already noticed 0 and basically anything you find in `timezone_abbreviations_list()` )

**UPDATE**:

I thought I'd share my "turn various inputs into PHP Datetime object" function with you all. Originally done as a conditional "whatever I'm handed, output an object", but thanks to @Syscall's input I've been able to harden it a bit against spurious inputs that inappropriately return "now" datetimes.

I could crank this down even harder against various timezone strings, but I don't think it's necessary for my usage.

```
/**
 * If $input is already a DateTime object, leave it alone. Otherwise convert to a DateTime object
 * If $immutable = true, converts strings OR DateTime to DateTimeImmutable
 * Can be used to convert DateTimeInterface objects to and from immutable
 *
 * @param string|\DatetimeInterface $input
 * @param bool $immutable
 * @return \DateTime|\DateTimeImmutable|\DateTimeInterface|null
 */
function ensureDateTime ( $input, $immutable = NULL ) {
    if ( ! $input instanceof \DateTimeInterface ) {
        $output = NULL;
        if( is_string( $input ) || ! $input ) {
            $trimmed = trim( $input, ".,\n\0\t " ); // Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/48956505/339440
            $ignore =  ( $trimmed == '' && $trimmed != $input )
              || in_array( $trimmed, ['0000-00-00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'], true )
              || ( strlen( $trimmed ) == 1 && preg_match( '#[a-zA-Z]#', $trimmed ) == 1 );
            if ( ! $ignore ) {
                try {
                    $input = trim( $input );
                    if ( $immutable ) {
                        $output = new \DateTimeImmutable( $input );
                    } else {
                        $output = new \DateTime( $input );
                    }
                } catch( \Exception $e ) {
                    // suppress DateTime::__construct() errors.  $output remains NULL
                }
            }
        }
    } elseif ( true === $immutable && $input instanceof \DateTime ) {
        $output = new \DateTimeImmutable( $input->format(TIMESTAMPFORMAT), $input->getTimezone() );
    } elseif ( false === $immutable && $input instanceof \DateTimeImmutable ) {
        $output = new \DateTime( $input->format(TIMESTAMPFORMAT), $input->getTimezone() );
    } else {
        $output = $input;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: See if you can find anything here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: I've updated my anwser including reference to the PHP source code.

Comment: It's called ["garbage in, garbage out"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Comment: Yes, and sometimes we have to write code that deals with data that may or may not be garbage — such as my function that detects whether or not a particular input is a valid date or not. I can’t help that the system I inherited had a text field for a date, or that some users entered things like “next Tuesday” or “N/A” or... yes indeed, “.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values `".,\n\0\t "` are trimmed :

See `/php-7.2.2/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c`, `static int scan()` :

```
switch (yych) {
case 0x00:
case '\n':  goto yy51;
case '\t':
case ' ':   goto yy48;
case ',':
case '.':   goto yy50;
```

Other characters like `(+-@`, letters, numbers, requires other validation.

Example :

```
new Datetime("\0 \n\t,."); // works
```

But :

```
new Datetime('@') ; // fails
```